# Random Forest or other machine learning techniques with paired samples

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, paired-data

I am trying to select features from paired samples and was wondering if there are methods out there that adapt random Forest or other machine learning algorithms to paired samples i.e. if randomForest was a machine learning analog to a standard FDR-corrected ANOVA approach, what would be the machine learning analog be of a paired t-test between two categories?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for, perhaps with a specific example? I don't really follow the first part of the analogy you're making.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because needs clarifications to be answerable, and OP is long gone